# xml file error in android

Tags: android, xml

hi have problem when i view graphical.layout of this file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is main text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

when i view graphical layout of this view this xml file then this warning show 
[I18N] Hardcoded string "this is main text", should use @string resource
but i dont want to declare string valiable i want to show this "this is main text" without declaring string

Comment: its more advisable to declare all strings related to design should declare in string.xml...
if you dont want to do that then just ignore this warning...!!

Comment: @adnan this is lint warning you can ignore it

Comment: This is just a warning for your kind of information,using "@string" and declaring names in it is a good Android practice so if you dont want to use @string just ignore it.

Comment: Why do you want one to be a string resource but not the other?

Answer (score 1):

The warning about 'should use @string resource' is just a reminder that locale-specific information should be placed in 'resource bundles' (eg /res/values/strings.xml) so that labels and other text can be provided in different languages without having to re-code and recompile the entire application for each language.

If you're just testing things out, you can safely ignore that warning, but it's a good idea to get in the habit of referencing strings as resources in external files rather than hardcoding them directly in the application itself.

It is not good practice to hard code strings into your layout files. You should add them to a string resource file and then reference them from your layout.

refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743887/1364120) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272792/1364120) also.

Answer (score 0):

```
You must declare your text using `@string` resource that 
 is a good programming format.You should prefer using 
 `string.xml` in value folder in res folder if you want
 to use texts.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress the specific warning use
tools:ignore="HardcodedText"

more details
http://tools.android.com/recent/ignoringlintwarnings